# Kafka - Unbalanced consumer_offsets

Tags: apache-kafka

I see in a Kafka installation the size of the different 50(in my case) partitions of __customer_offsets is very uneven, with half of them having size 0.

[image]

Is this normal, or is it an indication of something going wrong or suboptimal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal.

The hashes of the consumer group name strings that your clients are using may cause "hotspots" in those partitions since those names are the keys of the offset records.